# MAMP ошибка при заходе на My website

Tags: php, mamp

Итак, проблема заключается вот в чём: хостинг я нашёл, залил туда свои файлы, захожу в mamp, нажимаю на my website и тут вылазит это чудо: "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Я не опытен! Я еще не много понимаю, даже если это кажется глупым.
Я смотрел видео, по тому, как сделать на php авторизацию и регистрацию, дошёл до этого этапа, делал всё так же, но в видео там совсем не это чудо-текст.

Comment: Эта ошибка говорит, что у вас нет прав на папку и файлы для их исполнения. Поставьте права на чтение и запись на файлы и папки проекта

Comment: @mepihindeveloper А как это сделать?

Comment: Смотря какая у вас ОС. Прочитайте как в вашей ОС назначить права для записи на папки и файлы. Возможно видео поможет: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rv_yjQf4hLw

Comment: @mepihindeveloper Благодарю, нашёл зарубежное видео, человек просто поставил галочку в Apache "indexes, она у меня была поставлена, я убрал в Directory index путь к файлу - и заработало как надо.

Спасибо :D

(можно же это как ответ опубликовать, или как новый ответ?)